# How can search records from a box search with special characters on Laravel and psql

Tags: php, laravel, psql

I've a question, and it's, I've a box search, where all users can search records from a table in database, the problem is with special characters, because when the record in database looks like this " Canción" and the user type and search " Cancion " the result is null, and don't get any result, butn, obviously, if they put " Canción " they got all the records with the title Canción. The function is this; I'm using ILIKE to compare, but didn't worl of all. and I'm using postgres.

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $search, $option)
    {
        if ($search !="")
        {
            if ($option == 'all')
            {
                 $query->where('title', 'Ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                 ->orWhere('author', 'Ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                 ->orWhere('description', 'Ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                 ->orWhere('keywords', 'Ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                 ->orWhere('section', 'Ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
            }
            else
            {
                $query->where($option, 'ILIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help. I'll be gratefull

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can directly solve with Laravel alone. Maybe the unaccent function of Postgres can do the trick. I never used it myself but I think it might be what you are looking for.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html